# How do I remove the size control from a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to get rid of the row resizer on the left side of the datagrid and I cant seem to do it.

I am using **WPF xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ProcessDatagrid" Height="130" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEEEE" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" 
          SelectedCellsChanged="ProcessDatagrid_SelectedCellsChanged" CanUserResizeColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"  Binding="{Binding Path=Pid, Mode=OneWay}" Width="50"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: datagrid]

Comment: How about `RowHeaderWidth="0"`?

Comment: That did it!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth` can do that:

```
<DataGrid
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    ...
```

Or use `DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle` to collapse them:

```
<DataGrid 
    ... 
    >
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: I added the RowHeaderStyle to no avail damn

Comment: @PaulBaxter It's working for me (both are). Can you add the RowHeaderStyle version of the DataGrid to your question? What about `RowHeaderWidth="0"`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks.The first time only set collapsed in tn the style

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to accomplish that is to set the `HeadersVisibility` property of the `DataGrid`. In your case:

```
<DataGrid
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ...
```

Comment: This is the real answer!

Answer (score 0):

You set CanUserResizeColumns but try CanUserResizeRows = "False" inside of your DataGrid

Comment: Ed got it. I realized what he was asking right before I saw his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding     ElementName=ColX,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=ColY, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
           <DataGrid Style="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" SelectedIndex="-1" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                                                                         <DataGrid.Columns> 
                                                            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColX" Header="X (nm)" Binding="{Binding X, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" />          
                                                          <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ColY" Header="Y (nm)" Binding="{Binding Y, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" /> 
                                                              </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Its still there. crap